# How specific to weapons is too specific to weapons?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am wondering whether [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/18996/in-current-missile-what-is-the-guidance-law-used-at-terminal-phase-in-homing-mi) is in scope or not. If we had a Military.SE, it would be easy to redirect this question there, but that is not the case.

It seems to me like this question strictly has to do with the navigational system of a missile and thus is not related to aviation. Furthermore, the elements discussed in that question are not equally applicable to aircraft. As such, I believe it is off topic.

As said in the answer to [another meta question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1730/3775):

> we want to stay away from questions about the tactical/strategic function of the ordinance, it's damage capabilities or it's guidance system.

BUT, I have not voted to close, as I realize it is very close to a borderline. Terminal phase navigation on missiles can be used to target aircraft (but then again, so can shotguns, and I'm pretty sure those are off topic).

We do have a ``missiles'' tag, but questions with that tag usually do have aircraft somewhere in the question.

- missiles being shot from planes

  - [Do fighter jets experience a reaction or recoil force upon firing a missile?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15684/do-fighter-jets-experience-a-reaction-or-recoil-force-upon-firing-a-missile),
  - [How can you stop your missile locking onto a friendly target?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15337/how-can-you-stop-your-missile-locking-onto-a-friendly-target)
- or missiles that target planes

  - [How does a Missile Lock Work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15942/how-does-a-missile-lock-work),
  - [How are anti-aircraft missiles tested?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7967/how-are-anti-aircraft-missiles-tested)
- or systems that protect planes from missiles

  - [Why don't airliners carry radar jamming technology or missile counter measures?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/why-dont-airliners-carry-radar-jamming-technology-or-missile-counter-measures)

---

A lot has been said about this question, as [an Area51 question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/will-missiles-and-missiles-technology-be-a-part-of-this-aviation-and-aerospace), [another meta post](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/418/why-was-my-question-closed-as-off-topic/1475#1475) and [a chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25145/discussion-between-sentryraven-and-victor-juliet) can prove. But does [the question at the top](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/18996/in-current-missile-what-is-the-guidance-law-used-at-terminal-phase-in-homing-mi) fall out of scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Moderator Hat Off**
This question appears to be entirely about missile guidance.
It has nothing to do with aircraft, aerodynamics, or aviation (save that the missile was presumably launched from an aircraft, and could possibly be homing in on another aircraft), so personally I don't think it's a good fit for the site as it stands.

**Moderator Hat On**
Topicality is really a mater for the larger community to decide - that's why we have close votes, and why it takes 5 of them to make a question go away.
If you think it's not a good fit you should vote to close it. Generally if you follow your gut with close votes you'll usually do the right thing (and if on reflection you think you screwed up don't worry: It takes 4 other people screwing up to do any real damage).

Comment: Thank you for the moderator hat on insight.

Answer (score -2):

Far too specific to missile design, no longer related to Aviation. This is definitely 'off topic'.

I'm also slightly concerned as to why the asker wants to know.